# What endianess is used to store information in call to recvfrom()

Tags: networking, c, sockets

Here is a simple code in socket API:

`sock_raw = socket(AF_PACKET,SOCK_RAW,htons(ETH_P_ALL));`

`//...`

`data_size = recvfrom(sock_raw , buffer , bufsize , 0 , (struct sockaddr*)&saddr , (socklen_t*)&saddr_size);`

`//...`

`void print_ethernet_header(unsigned char* buffer)
{
        struct ethhdr *eth = (struct ethhdr *)buffer;
        fprintf(logfile , "   |-Protocol            : %x    \n",ntohs(eth->h_proto));
}`

In this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/435233/why-protocol-type-value-for-ip-protocol-in-ethernet-frame-is-8) I was explained that `h_proto` member of `struct ethhdr` is stored in big-endian format.
Is it valid to say that the other members of this structure(`h_source` and `h_dest` are as well stored in big-endian format? And in such case is it valid to say that recvfrom() function stores data to buffer in big-endian format (I failed to find any info about this in man page to this function)? I think that this should be true because of [rfc1042](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1042.txt), but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`recvfrom` reads data from a socket and stores it in a buffer, but it doesn’t process the data: it stores it as it’s received. The order of values in the data depends on the network protocol. Most network protocols use big-endian (“network order”), so the data provided by `recvfrom` is typically big-endian — but that’s not a result of `recvfrom`.

In most cases you should use `ntohs` and `ntohl` to translate values as appropriate, and process arrays in the documented order. For `h_source` and `h_dest`, the documented order is indeed big-endian. If you’re writing kernel code, there are usually macros or helper functions available to do this for you; even `printk` has [`%pM` format specifiers](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/core-api/printk-formats.rst) to handle MAC addresses.